# Who is Aegon Targaryen?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* season 3 somewhere Jorah Mormont said that a dragon is worth more than any army and Barristan Selmy confirmed it with saying that:

> Aegon Targaryen proved that.

And in the season 7 final episode Bran Stark said about Jon Snow:

> His name is Aegon Targaryen.

So I'm wondering, are there two Aegon Targaryens in the series?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Aegon I Targaryen, also known as Aegon the Conqueror](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen) was the one (along with his sisters/wives Rhaenys, and Visenya) who united the Seven Kingdoms through the use of of his dragons, Balerion, Meraxes, and Vhagar. This is whom Ser Barristan is referring to.

Aegon has been used numerous times since [(at least 12)](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon) in Targaryen family. Much like a real royal family, the popular names get reused.

In the show universe there are even [two more Aegons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168222/why-are-there-two-characters-named-aegon) we are introduced to, both sons of Rhaegar...

- Aegon the son of Rhaegar Targaryen and Elia Martell (killed during the sack of King's Landing during Robert's Rebellion)
- Aegon the son of Rhaegar Targaryen and Lyanna Stark (aka Jon Snow)

It is possible that Rhaegar was naming his sons Aegon due to prophecy. The quote below is about naming his first born son.

> The man had her brother's hair, but he was taller, and his eyes were a dark indigo rather than lilac. "Aegon," he said to a woman nursing a newborn babe in a great wooden bed. "What better name for a king?"
>
> "Will you make a song for him?" the woman asked.
>
> "He has a song," the man replied. "He is the prince that was promised, and his is the song of ice and fire." He looked up when he said it and his eyes met Dany's, and it seemed as if he saw her standing there beyond the door. "There must be one more," he said, though whether he was speaking to her or the woman in the bed she could not say. "The dragon has three heads."
>
> <sub>*A Clash of Kings - Daenerys IV*</sub>

Comment: Actually you answered my another question too , that I was about to ask about mother of Jon Snow.

Comment: By the way , could some one tell me why "h" letter isn't written in Jo(h)n Snow?

Comment: @Vahid2017 ... because Jon is a fairly common alternative to John, or abbreviation of Jonathan.  There are at least 3 common spellings of my first name ... none of them is more "correct" than the other.  Jon is his name, not John.

Comment: Also there are many examples right through GoT [& SOI&F] of *'nearly english'* names being twisted by a letter or two, just to make it feels less like medieval Britain.

Comment: @iandotkelly: Additionally, GRRM has a thing for using "real" names but slightly tweaking them, which the less commonly known spelling of "Jon" can also be an instance of. I don't have a link but he said in an interview that he uses this to have "real sounding fantasy names".

Answer (score 3):

The Aegon Targaryen referred to by Barristan is the first Aegon, there are lots of them in the Targaryen family as you can see in this [family tree](http://awoiaf.westeros.org:8080/images/c/c6/House_Targaryen_Family_tree.jpg).

Aegon The Conqueror as defined by the song of ice and fire [wiki](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen):

> Aegon I Targaryen, also known as Aegon the Conqueror and Aegon the Dragon, was the first Lord of the Seven Kingdoms and king on the Iron Throne, having conquered six of the Seven Kingdoms during the Conquest. The dragonlord was the founder of the ruling Targaryen dynasty of Westeros.

Jon Snow name is simply the same as the late Aegon The Conqueror, but Jon Snow is the son of Rhaegar Targaryen and Lyanna Stark.